# How to get a able-of-content as a grid cell with a fixed position (with right-hand side article scrollable)

Tags: html, css, layout, grid, sticky

I have a grid layout composed of 2 headers underneath which you find two grid cells: on the left-hand side a table of content, and on the right-hand side the content of an article. I need the second header to have a fixed position when the pages is scrolled, so I have set it to `position: sticky; top: 0`. This works.

But I would (also) need the table-of-content on the left-hand side to be sticky as well. The closest i have found in terms of design is this [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal) (so that you get an idea of what the result I am aiming for).

[image]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fpdewuxq/#&togetherjs=KdRq5BebsV)

I tried to get it to stick by nesting a `div` inside the `toc` element and setting this `div` position to `fixed`. However

1. when I scroll down, the header (in grey) disappear, the  yellow header sticks, and it leaves some extra white space above the table of content. I'd ideally want the table of content to scroll down while the grey header is visible as well. The only solution I'd know to make it work is to write some javascript.
2. if the windows gets narrow, the article overlays the table-of-content. Clearly not desirable).

How can this be done in `css`? (this seems like a very common layout so hope it is achievable without javascript). Your expertise and help is very much appreciated.

### EDIT

I managed to make some progress. See below. But I would have to use Javascript to keep the toc element from scrolling when the second headers get stuck. And for now I put a "magic number" for the height of the header. I would of course need to get this value in the js. There must be a way of doing this in HTML/CSS).

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    console.log("scrolling" + window.pageYOffset);
    var toc = document.getElementById("toc");
    toc.style.top = Math.min(window.pageYOffset, 30) + "px";
});
</script>


<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: [l1] minmax(auto, 300px) [l2] minmax(auto, 960px) [l3]; grid-template-rows: [r1] 32px [r2] 32px [r3] auto [r4]; position: relative;">
    <div style="grid-column: l1 / span 2; border: 1px solid green;">header</div>
    <div style="grid-column: l1 / span 2; border: 1px solid green; position: sticky; top: 0;">header 2</div>
    <div id="toc" style="position: sticky; top: 0px; height: 100vh;">
        <ul>
        <li>test 1</li>
        <li>test 1</li>
        <li>test 1</li>
        <li>test 1</li>
        <li>test 1</li>
        <li>test 1</li>
        <li>test 1</li>
        <li>test 1</li>
        <li>test 1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div style="border: 1px solid red; font-size: 2rem;">
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
  .toc {top: 15px; align-self: start;}
```